# Numpy reduce with char operations

Tags: numpy, reduce

I want a vectorized way to do:

`numpy.char.add.reduce(["string_", values.astype("U"), "_string"], axis=0)`

So, for example, I might want to send `[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]` to `["string_0.1_string", "string_0.2_string", "string_0.3_string"]`. However, `values` will have an arbitrary shape and may be huge.

However, it doesn't seem like `numpy.char.add` is a ufunc, and one cannot just do `numpy.char.add.reduce`.

Is there a well-documented work around, or do I need to do something clever?

Comment: `np.char` functions are shallow wrappers for python string methods.  They aren't fast.  Explain or illustrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: Okay, done @hpaulj

Comment: Is that just a string `join`?

Comment: In this case, even if it was implemented in Numpy the way you want, it would be more expensive than a `join` because the strings and the array are small. Creating a Numpy array is far more expensive than a CPython string. Numpy does not support operating on lists, so they need to be converted to a Numpy array.

Comment: Thanks @JérômeRichard. The two things most important to me are (1) broadcasting, not duplicating, the strings, since the final shape will usually be huge, and (2) vectorizing the concatenation.

Comment: just use vanilla python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is there a simple way to handle broadcasting and vectorization with vanilla python

Comment: As explained by hpaulj, Numpy will use CPython strings internally (for unicode strings only, AFAIK not ASCII ones). This means Numpy will operate on CPython objects and thus this operation *cannot* be vectorized. The only way to vectorize the operation is to use ASCII strings in Numpy or use another library supporting that supporting broadcasting (I do not know any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample list/array:

```
In [71]: x=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]; xx = np.array(x,'U5');xx
Out[71]: array(['0.1', '0.2', '0.3'], dtype='<U5')
```

As is clear from the docs, `char.add` is not a `ufunc`.  It is just a shallow wrapper around the relevant string method.

But we can chain the `add`, same as if we did `'string_'+'0.01'+'_string'):

```
In [72]: np.char.add(np.char.add('string_',xx),'_string')
Out[72]: 
array(['string_0.1_string', 'string_0.2_string', 'string_0.3_string'],
      dtype='<U19')
```

`numpy` doesn't have special code for handling strings, so the `char` functions generally operate at the same speed as a list comprehension.

There is a `char.join`, but it operates on the characters of the array:

```
In [74]: np.char.join('_',xx)
Out[74]: array(['0_._1', '0_._2', '0_._3'], dtype='<U5')
```

Another approach is to use `np.vectorize` or `np.frompyfunc` with a utility function like:

```
In [75]: def foo(i):
    ...:     return '_'.join(['string',str(i),'string'])
    ...:     

In [76]: np.frompyfunc(foo,1,1)(x)
Out[76]: 
array(['string_0.1_string', 'string_0.2_string', 'string_0.3_string'],
      dtype=object)
```

For small arrays `np.vectorize/frompyfunc` tend to be a bit slower than list comprehensions, but they scale better for large arrays.

But the main advantage is that they handle multiple dimensions and broadcasting.

Comment: Okay. vectorize/frompyfunc are almost certainly the way to go then. Thanks